# Bloch-Messiah decomposition for 2-mode Gaussian unitary

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-optics, lie-algebra

The Bloch-Messiah decomposition states that any Gaussian unitary can be decomposed as a sequence of passive elements and single-mode squeezers (i.e. beamsplitters, rotations, single-mode squeezing). How does one find this decomposition in practice? For example, say I have the quadratic 2-mode unitary:

\begin{align}
U = e^{a^\dagger b + a^2} 
\end{align}
My first thought is to make the ansatz:
\begin{align}
U = R(\phi_1) B(\theta) R(\phi_2) S_1(r_1) S_1(r_2) \equiv RBRS_1S_1
\end{align}
where $R,B,S_1$ are respectively rotations, beamsplitter, and squeezing unitaries. Then one can show that:
\begin{align}
 (RBRS_1S_1)^\dagger U(RBRS_1S_1) = RBRS_1S_1 = U
\end{align}
Thus equating
\begin{align}
U =(RBRS_1S_1)^\dagger U (RBRS_1S_1)
\end{align}
one should be able to obtain the coefficients $\phi_1, \phi_2 , \theta, r_1,r_2$. However computing the right-hand side of the above equation is very tedious due to non-commutativity of the elements in the original $U$ and the unitaries $R,B,...$

Is there a simpler way to implement the Bloch-Messiah decomposition to find the appropriate decomposition in terms of the parameters $\phi_1, \phi_2,...$?